# N Nearest Neighbours efficiently PostGIS/Python

Tags: python, postgis, nearest-neighbor

The data is worldwide about a million points, lat/lons, with an id and an importance value (0.0 to 1.0), and it's limited to being on land.

Ideally I need to cluster all 1 million points into 100,000 clusters each with 10 elements within,, the shape of the cluster, and the distance between the elements is secondary to the number of points in the cluster, but it'd be nice to have them close to each other

I've just started looking at scikit-learn but haven't managed to get it to make clusters of a fixed size,

Have I missed something in scikit-learn?

I'm currently stuck on postgis 1.5

This code will download the 500K file, it's the California house prices sample, the rendering in the graph isn't great:

[image: python vis]

So it also connects to Postgres and creates PostGIS geom for the points, and the clusters in a new schema scikit_learn, and it's a bit clear to see that the clusters are not small.

HOW DO I LIMIT IT TO JUST USING THE DISTANCE BETWEEN POINTS, rather that the data values
Thanks

[image: same but viewed in QGIS]

Complete code:

```
DB = 'postgres'
USER = 'postgres'
HOST = 'localhost'

import psycopg2

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as p3
import time
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering
from sklearn import datasets

SCHEMA = 'scikit_learn'
TABLE = SCHEMA + '.scikit_learn_table'

connectionString = "dbname=%s user=%s host=%s" % (DB, USER, HOST)
conn = psycopg2.connect(connectionString)

create_schema = "CREATE SCHEMA  \"scikit_learn\" ;"

drop_table = " \
        DROP TABLE \
        \"scikit_learn\".\"scikit_learn_table\" "

create_table = " \
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS \
        \"scikit_learn\".\"scikit_learn_table\" ( \
        \"CAL_ID\" numeric not null, \
        \"IMPORTANCE\" numeric default 0,\
        \"POINT_WGS\" geometry not null,\
        \"CLUSTER_GEOM\" geometry default null,\
        \"CLUSTER_ID\" integer default null,\
        \"PARENT_ID\" integer default null );"

def insert_california_housing(X):
    cur = conn.cursor()
    clearq =  "DELETE FROM \"scikit_learn\".\"scikit_learn_table\" ;"
    cur.execute(clearq)
    for i in range (len (XData)):
        q = "INSERT INTO \"scikit_learn\".\"scikit_learn_table\" (\
            \"CAL_ID\" , \
             \"IMPORTANCE\" ,\
             \"POINT_WGS\" \
        ) VALUES (\
            {i} ,\
            {importance} / {maximp} ,     \
            ST_GeomFromEWKT ( 'SRID=4326;POINT({lon} {lat})' ) ); ".format\
        ( i=i, importance=XData[i,2], maximp = XData[:,2].max(), lat = XData[i,0], lon = XData[i,1]  )
        try:
            cur.execute(q)
        except Exception, e:
            print e , q
    conn.commit()
    cur.close()

def update_california_housing_clusters(labels, keys):
    cur = conn.cursor()
    clearq =  "UPDATE  \"scikit_learn\".\"scikit_learn_table\" set \"CLUSTER_GEOM\" = null, \"CLUSTER_ID\" = 0 where \"CLUSTER_ID\" <> 0 OR \"CLUSTER_GEOM\" is NOT NULL;"
    try:
        cur.execute(clearq)
    except Exception, e:
        print e , clearq
        cur.close()
        cur = conn.cursor()
    for i in range (len (keys)):
        q = "UPDATE  \"scikit_learn\".\"scikit_learn_table\" set \"CLUSTER_ID\" = {cluster_fkey_value} \
                where \"CAL_ID\" = {key_value}  ; ".format\
        ( key_value=i, cluster_fkey_value = labels[i] )
        try:
            cur.execute(q)
        except Exception, e:
            print e , q
            cur.close()
            cur = conn.cursor()

    conn.commit()

    create = "update \"scikit_learn\".\"scikit_learn_table\"   \
    set \"CLUSTER_GEOM\" = nn.the_geom from ( \
        SELECT ST_ConvexHull(ST_Collect(\"POINT_WGS\")) As the_geom, \"CLUSTER_ID\" \
        FROM \"scikit_learn\".\"scikit_learn_table\" GROUP BY \"CLUSTER_ID\" \
    ) nn  \
       where \"scikit_learn\".\"scikit_learn_table\".\"CLUSTER_ID\" <> 0 \
       and nn.\"CLUSTER_ID\" = \"scikit_learn\".\"scikit_learn_table\".\"CLUSTER_ID\"  ; "
    try:
        cur.execute(create)
    except Exception, e:
        print 'Exception', e
        cur.close()
        cur = conn.cursor()
    conn.commit()
    regGeom = "INSERT INTO geometry_columns(f_table_catalog, f_table_schema, f_table_name, f_geometry_column, coord_dimension, srid, \"type\") \
        SELECT '', 'scikit_learn', 'scikit_learn_table', 'CLUSTER_GEOM', ST_CoordDim(\"CLUSTER_GEOM\"), ST_SRID(\"CLUSTER_GEOM\"), GeometryType(\"CLUSTER_GEOM\")\
    FROM \"scikit_learn\".\"scikit_learn_table\" LIMIT 1;"
    try:
        cur.execute(regGeom)
    except Exception, e:
        print 'Exception', e
        cur.close()
        cur = conn.cursor()
    conn.commit()
    regGeomPoint = "INSERT INTO geometry_columns(f_table_catalog, f_table_schema, f_table_name, f_geometry_column, coord_dimension, srid, \"type\") \
        SELECT '', 'scikit_learn', 'scikit_learn_table', 'POINT_WGS', ST_CoordDim(\"POINT_WGS\"), ST_SRID(\"POINT_WGS\"), GeometryType(\"POINT_WGS\")\
    FROM \"scikit_learn\".\"scikit_learn_table\" LIMIT 1;"
    try:
        cur.execute(regGeomPoint)
    except Exception, e:
        print 'Exception', e
        cur.close()
        cur = conn.cursor()
    conn.commit()
    cur.close()

#########################
main_cur = conn.cursor()
try:
    main_cur.execute(create_schema)
except Exception, e:
    print 'schema may already have been created ' , e
    main_cur.close()
    conn.commit()
    main_cur = conn.cursor()

try:
   main_cur.execute(drop_table)
except Exception, e:
    print 'table may not already have been created ', e
    main_cur.close()
    conn.commit()
    main_cur = conn.cursor()

try:
   main_cur.execute(create_table)
except Exception, e:
    print 'table may already have been created ', e
    main_cur.close()
    conn.commit()
    main_cur = conn.cursor()

conn.commit()
main_cur.close()

###################
#note this downloads 500K of test data
X = datasets.fetch_california_housing ()

n_samples = len (X.data)
XData = X.data

#put x, y first
rearrange = np.array([6, 7, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
XData = XData [:, rearrange]
insert_california_housing ( XData )
XData = XData [:,0:3]
from sklearn.neighbors import kneighbors_graph
connectivity = kneighbors_graph(XData, n_neighbors=10)

st = time.time()
ward = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=n_samples/10, connectivity=connectivity,
                               linkage='ward').fit(XData)
elapsed_time = time.time() - st
labels = ward.labels_
print("Elapsed time: %.2fs" % elapsed_time)
print("Number of points: %i" % labels.size)

update_california_housing_clusters(labels, XData)

# ###############################################################################
# # Plot result
fig = plt.figure()
ax = p3.Axes3D(fig)
ax.view_init(7, -80)
for l in np.unique(labels):
    ax.plot3D(XData[labels == l, 0], XData[labels== l, 1], XData[labels == l, 2],
              'o', color=plt.cm.jet(float(l) / np.max(labels + 1)))
plt.title('With connectivity constraints (time %.2fs)' % elapsed_time)

plt.show()
```

Comment: The most efficient data structure for performing nearest neighbour analysis is a k-d tree. I use them all the time with point sets numbering in the millions. I'm not sure whether Python or post have implementations though.

Comment: does scikit support k-means clustering?

Comment: I'll edit my Q. add in some test code, but yes scikit-learn has k-nn and k-means clustering based on it, but the clusters generated are (of course) vary in elements and the nearest neighbour graph seems to "jump" across the map, so that the clusters formed are very wide, but narrow.  I'm testing it with a slice of Europe 10 degrees wide , 40 high and the clusters are 8-10 degrees wide.

Comment: Ok, I've trimmed  the data to loose the values, i.e. XData = XData [:,0:2], I think I'll have to work with the variation in number of points in the clusters.